# How to create a new column based on two other columns in Pandas?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, dataframe

I am searching for a way to create a new column in my data. I have tried using iterows() but found it extremely time consuming in my dataset containing 40 lakh rows. So here is what I want.
Consider I have 2 columns:
Event ID, TeamID ,I want to find the no. of unique TeamID under each EventID as a new column. In other words, I want to find the number of teams participating in each event as a new column.

Comment: Something like a groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to get a new dataframe that has pairs of (EventID, TeamCount):

```
event_id_team_count = data.groupby('EventID').agg({'TeamID': lambda x: x.nunique()})
event_id_team_count.rename(columns={"TeamID": "TeamCount"}, inplace=True)
```

If you want to have this new column in the original dataframe, all you need to do is to join the original dataframe with the one you have just created:

```
data = data.join(other=event_id_team_count, on="EventID")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a dictionary with the unique count of TeamID with respective to EventID

```
uCountDict = dict(data.groupby("EventID").TeamID.count())
uCountDict
```

Sample output
{'A': 4,
 'C': 3,
 'D': 2,
 'F': 1
}

2. Now create a new column with unique count with respective to TeamID using apply function

```
data["TeamCount"] = data.EventID.apply(lambda x : uCountDict[x])
```